# How to proceed with this integral in Mathematica?

Tags: definite-integrals, mathematica

NIntegrate[
Cos[2 1 Pi (2 Sqrt[(n + 8854800957672623)^2 -
78407500000000000000000000000000] + 0) -
Pi]/(2 1 Pi)^2 (1000000/(10^40 Pi^8 (Sqrt[
2 (Sqrt[(n + 8854800957672623)^2 -
78407500000000000000000000000000] + 0.001)^2  +
313630000000000000000000000000000] -
Sqrt[2 (Sqrt[(n + 8854800957672623)^2 -
78407500000000000000000000000000])^2  +
313630000000000000000000000000000])^8 + 1))
, {n, 10^8, 10^16}, MaxRecursion -> 500]

The first part of the function is an highly oscillating function and the second part is a polynomial function, I've tried using various methods; "Global Adaptive", "LevinRule", but they are not working, the Global Adaptive seems to be the best option so far but its not monotonically decreasing after a number of integrand evaluations and hence not converging.

Additional Input It is accurately solving the problem from 0 to Infinity, which is weird.

Comment: I honestly think that for this question, you don't need to include the wall of math equation, and just ask what are some good ways to deal with oscillating functions. There probably is already a question about dealing with oscillating functions in Mathematica though

Comment: @gst076923 yeah you're right. I just thought to post the code incase someone else wanted to take a stab at it, I've tried a bulk of the methods for highly oscillating functions and they are not working sadly.